# return status of command sent to host via ssh

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script that open up cores on machine
It works fine, but if I enhance it, like if there are not cores
on the machine, I would like it to tell me, not just kick out an
error command. I would like to replace the error with something
So I am trying to ge the exit status of the last command and base the
if statement off of that.

```
#!/bin/bash
rc=$?
for i in server5432foo server5438foo server5344foo server5430foo;
do
echo $i ;
ssh -q -T $i " ls -ltr  /local/data/log/core*; echo $? ";
echo $rc

if [[ $rc == 0 ]] ; then
    ssh -q -T $i " chmod ugo+rw  /local/data/log/core* ";
    else
    echo " No core files on $i /local/data/log/ "
    fi
done
```

This is what the script returns where there are no
cores in the file specified. Even though the ls is unsuccessful it still
returns a 0 and does not run the else command.

```
ls: cannot access /local/data/log/core*: No such file or directory
0
0
chmod: cannot access `/local/data/log/core*': No such file or directory
```

I am trying to get the return code on the commnand sent to that box vias ssh.
In the script it seems that the SSH is successful, so it returns a zero.
However when I run the command from the shell - I get a return code other than zero if it is unsuccessful.

```
casper@server0170foo:~/walt/restart_superprocesss$ ssh -q -T server5432foo "ls -ltr   /local/data/log/core00001" ; echo $?
ls: cannot access /local/data/log/core00001: No such file or directory
2
casper@server0170foo:~/walt/restart_superprocesss$ ssh -q -T server5432foo "touch    /local/data/log/core00001" ; echo $?
0
casper@server0170foo:~/walt/restart_superprocesss$ ssh -q -T server5432foo "ls -ltr    /local/data/log/core00001" ; echo $?
-rw-r--r-- 1 casper casper 0 Oct 13 11:38 /local/data/log/core00001
0
```

How come the return code is different from when I run a command directly from the command line, which are accurate as opposed
to running the command from a script - where I get a 0 everytime

Comment: rc=$? ... if [[ $rc == 0 ]] at no point do you actually look at the return code from ssh

Comment: Where exactly is your current code ever setting/modifying `rc`, other than at its very beginning (when `$?` isn't yet at a useful value)?

Comment: ...also, since `ssh` passes back its shell's exit status, you could, and would, have the *exact* same problem even if ssh were not used. Easier to ask the problem, and find an answer for it, with fewer potentially-confusing factors in play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following:

```
for i in server5432foo server5438foo server5344foo server5430foo; do
    echo $i;

    if ssh -q -T $i " ls -ltr /local/data/log/core* > /dev/null; then
        ssh -q -T $i "chmod ugo+rw  /local/data/log/core*"
    else
        echo "No core files on $i /local/data/log/"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Why the parens? Creating a subshell has costs -- you're doing an extra `fork()`, after all -- so it's best not done as a hail-Mary without an actual reason.

Comment: Just a habit. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: If you want a grouping operator that doesn't have performance-impacting side effects, consider curly braces: `if { ssh -q -T "$i" command-here >/dev/null; }; then ...` -- though note the extra semicolon required when using them here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the return status of `ssh` (which should be return status of the remotely executed command or some higher number indicating `ssh` itself failed), I think you have a bug in your script, and you want to remove the echo in the `ssh` statement, because it will exit with 0 (and because, with double-quotes, the `$?` will be the return value of the command before `ssh`, not the return value of the `ls`):

```
#!/bin/bash
# This line isn't really helpful
#rc=$?
for i in server5432foo server5438foo server5344foo server5430foo;
do
echo $i ;
ssh -q -T $i "ls -ltr /local/data/log/core*";
# This is the new line to make sure $rc has the ssh exit status
rc=$?
echo $rc

if [[ $rc == 0 ]] ; then
    ssh -q -T $i "chmod ugo+rw  /local/data/log/core*";
    else
    echo " No core files on $i /local/data/log/ "
    fi
done
```

From the man page:

> EXIT STATUS
>        ssh exits with the exit status of the remote command or with 255 if an error occurred.

Comment: I actually tend to suggest `ssh ...; rc=$?` on one line, to prevent any additional logging or future changes adding other content between the `ssh` and the reference to its `$?`.

Comment: @Duffy, that's a good pattern to follow. I honestly like to put it right in the if statement: `if ssh ...; then ... ; else ... ; fi`. Then you know exactly what why're testing.

Comment: Yup -- that's the better practice, for cases where you don't _actually_ need the rc returned/stored.